# Count specific words in a text using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How do I do this in jQuery?

For example I have a variable called paragraph

```
var paragraph = 'AAA BBB AAA CCC AAA AAA DDD EEE AAA';
```

I want to count all 'AAA' in the paragraph

I try to use `.val().match('AAA').length` it always gives me 1

Comment: `.match('AAA', 'g').length`

Comment: Sweet! Thats the answer I was looking for

Comment: The second parameter might not be supported by all browsers. Using `paragraph.match(/AAA/g).length​​​​​​` will work too.

Comment: If paragraph has variable word size and characters, then .match(/AAA/g) may not be best—would include match AAAAAAAAAAAA in the following example: 'AAA EEE AAA KHAAAAAAAAAAAAN AAA BBB'. Use .match(/\bAAA\b/g).length instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split the text, then count the remaining array

```
text.split('AAA').length - 1
```